# Laravel 5.1 - Session store not set on request

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to upgrade a Laravel 4.1 application to 5.1 on WAMP, and got this error:

> RuntimeException in Request.php line 775: Session store not set on
>   request.
>
> in
>   D:\wamp\www\laravel-5.1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Request.php
>   line 775 at Request->session() in
>   D:\wamp\www\laravel-5.1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php
>   line 137 at VerifyCsrfToken->addCookieToResponse(object(Request),
>   object(Response)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 64 at
>   VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   30 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php
>   line 96 at
>   ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(BrowseController),
>   object(Route), object(Request), 'getBrowseRecent') in
>   ControllerDispatcher.php line 54 at
>   ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request),
>   'App\Http\Controllers\BrowseController', 'getBrowseRecent') in
>   Route.php line 174 at Route->runController(object(Request)) in
>   Route.php line 140 at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line
>   703 at Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   139 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   ViewThrottleMiddleware.php line 55 at
>   ViewThrottleMiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(ViewThrottleMiddleware), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   30 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 705 at
>   Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in
>   Router.php line 678 at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in
>   Router.php line 654 at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php
>   line 246 at
>   Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   139 at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) in
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44 at
>   CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'),
>   array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124 at
>   Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line
>   103 at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132 at
>   Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line
>   99 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54

The `storage` folder is writable, and the session driver used is `file`. I searched the whole project for `session()`, but found it nowhere. What can I do to correct this error? Thanks!

The `session.php` is as follows:

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,

];
```

**Edit 1**: I found the problem is in the controller. There is a line:

```
$this->middleware('csrf', [ 'on' => 'post' ]);
```

I commented it out and it worked. But I didn't figure out why it caused the problem yet.

Comment: when does this error come in?

Comment: please show `sessions.php` config. And, are you following the documentations upgrade procedure?

Comment: I checked the upgrade documentation, and tried to remove `'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',` from `App\Http\Kernel`, but it didn't help. csrf still shows in `php artisan route:list` as middleware. Is this the reason?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 this link says that you will have to create another app with new framework dependency. And copy your 4.1 controllers route etc to the new app.

Comment: Thanks @VishalSh . Please see my update.

Comment: It is not advisable to turn off csrf verification as it is a security feature. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9632 there is a similar issue raised on laravel github.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Session store not set on request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

Answer (score 0):

Look at @Cas Bloem his answer here this helped me out amazingly:

[Laravel - Session store not set on request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34449770/laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request)

That's why it wasn't working for me. Cause you're using a session that is expection matching CSRF tokens (is my best guess, I'm new to Laravel myself).

Also if you go to app->http->middleware->VerifyCsrfToken this is were you can add routes to the array that won't be checked for CSRF verification. This plus Cas Bloem his fix (place routes in different section in routes.php) fixed my problem.  I'm just developing/learning on localhost right now but need to implement this later on.

Hope this helps/clears thing up!